# How to validate quantity being added to cart from frontend?

Tags: cart, checkout, quote, quantity

I'm trying to validate and correct quantities of certain products being added from the frontend. I've found the `checkout_cart_save_before` event that fires during all frontend cart modifications. This is good, but I'm trying to see if there's a better and more efficient way of doing this, as, when listening to this event, I'll have to iterate through all of the products each time the cart is updated. This event also fires twice during a single cart update.

I've thought about rewriting specific controller actions, but that can be too intrusive as some actions don't have a convenient events to listen to modify quote item quantities.

There's also a Javascript method for each of the pages.. I understand the answers may be kind of an opinion, but I'd still like to obtain some feedback on this.

Comment: what is the aim of this? are you trying to do something on product add or later on?

Comment: The idea is to impose a qty limit on specific products. `checkout_cart_save_before` works, but it fires twice when you add a product to cart (so you have to iterate through quote items twice) and only once when you simply reload/refresh/update the cart page. There's an alternative method I found to be better, and that's to listen to two separate events (add-to-cart and cart update events) separately.

Comment: not sure 100% when they are fired but have you looked at `catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options` and `catalog_product_type_prepare_lite_options` checkout http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/9606/158

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify a max quantity, you can set it on the product admin in the inventory tab. The name of the field is Maximum qty allowed in the shopping cart.