# client should buy minimum 2 kilo products then and then he should be able to proceed to check out

Tags: admin, checkout, magento-1.9

i have developed a online web store for my client and he has a query that the client (product buyer) should not be able to proceed to check out until he buys minimum 2 kilo product

Comment: Can you give a little more info? Do you need 2Kg total weight in the card? Do you need to set a minimum sales amount for one specific item? It's not quite clear from your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your weight validation using the event `catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options` as described in this answer:

[How to allow only one product in a cart?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9584/how-to-allow-only-one-product-in-a-cart)