# Anais accessories product invalid method

Tags: magento-1.8, product, import, query

@Marius,First of all, thank you for the great extension of accessory. I am currently using it to one of my store. Recently, I am facing an issue, may be you can help. From xml files, I am going to store stock inventory as follows:

```
    if($xmlObj) {                   
        $productStocks = $xmlObj->getXpath("//StockMessage/Stock");
        if(is_array($productStocks)) {                      
            foreach($productStocks as $productStock) {
                $productCode = (string)$productStock->ProductCodeSupplier;
                $availableStock = (string)$productStock->AvailableStock;
                $mainProductID = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($productCode);
                $stock = 1;
                //to set out of stock status
                if($availableStock == 0) {
                    $stock = 0;
                }
                if($mainProductID) {                                
                    $mainProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                    $mainProduct->load($mainProductID);
                    $mainProduct->setStockData(array( 
                        'is_in_stock' => $stock, 
                        'qty' => $availableStock 
                    ));
                    Mage::log('---------------------------------------------', null, $stockLogFileName,true);
                    Mage::log('Processed product '.$productCode.' with qty '.$availableStock.' dated on '.date("Y m d, H:i",time()), null, $stockLogFileName,true);
                    var_dump($mainProduct->__toString());
                    exit;
                    $mainProduct->save();
                }                           
            }
        }
    }
```

Above save method is actually giving me SQL constraint violation error as follows :

```
    a:5:{i:0;s:132:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7308-1-0-5.0000-0' for key 'E8AB433B9ACB00343ABB312AD2FAB087'";i:1;s:1870:"#0 /home2/store/public_html/app/Mage.php(462): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('eav/entity_attr...', 'SQLSTATE[23000]...')
    #1 /home2/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(661): Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attr...', 'SQLSTATE[23000]...')
    #2 /home2/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1648): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->walkAttributes('backend/afterSa...', Array)
    #3 /home2/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product.php(195): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_afterSave(Object(Anais_Accessories_Model_Product))
    #4 /home2/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1124): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product->_afterSave(Object(Anais_Accessories_Model_Product))
    #5 /home2/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->save(Object(Anais_Accessories_Model_Product))
    #6 /home2/store/public_html/app/code/local/MyCompany/Productimporter/controllers/IndexController.php(1155): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
    #7 /home2/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): MyCompany_Productimporter_IndexController->importStockAction()
    #8 /home2/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('importStock')
    #9 /home2/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #10 /home2/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #11 /home2/store/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #12 /home2/store/public_html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:34:"/productimporter/index/importStock";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

So, I was trying to debug the SQL query but somehow I am getting following error :

```
    a:5:{i:0;s:70:"Invalid method Anais_Accessories_Model_Product::__toString(Array
    (
    )
    )";i:1;s:1078:"#0 /home2/store/public_html/app/code/local/MyCompany/Productimporter/controllers/IndexController.php(1155): Varien_Object->__call('__toString', Array)
    #1 /home2/store/public_html/app/code/local/MyCompany/Productimporter/controllers/IndexController.php(1155): Anais_Accessories_Model_Product->__toString()
    #2 /home2/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): MyCompany_Productimporter_IndexController->importStockAction()
    #3 /home2/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('importStock')
    #4 /home2/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #5 /home2/store/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #6 /home2/store/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #7 /home2/store/public_html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:34:"/productimporter/index/importStock";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Ideally, it should print the query as Anais_Accessories_Model_Product is extending Mage_Catalog_Model_Product, but my bad. Can you please let me know what is wrong? [There is no issue with accessory product list.]. TIA.

Comment: This question seems to be an off-topic. I know this is a great extension. But the question is purely related to an external extension. For this you can raise an issue to @Marius.

Comment: Well, in my opinion, this is something related to magento community cause there can be same scenario where one product model can extend core product model.. BTW Thanks, I'll take care of it..

Comment: is it so ? Be not @Marius, and read this question, what will you feel ? It is realted to an extension or purely a magento related question. When I go through the question, I feel this question pointing to only one person. But in this community lot of other people out there. Please take this in good sense friend :)

Comment: I don't know if this is really of topic or not. What is off topic is the fact that mentioned a specific extension. But after looking through the code I realized the problem is not the extension. Is the custom code. So I guess custom code questions that provide the code should be allowed.  I suggest you do disable the extension and try your code. I think you will get the same error.

Comment: @Marius : You may be right. But looking on the appearance of the question, I feel no one except you gonna go through this deeply. If any one go through, it would not be easy to find that error that you mentioned in the answer. If I am wrong on this,  sorry from my heart :)

Comment: @Marius : after go through your answer, again I read this question. Now I feel it as ON-topic. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow only one product in a cart?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9584/how-to-allow-only-one-product-in-a-cart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah...that's not one of my best extensions.
I wrote it when I was still discovering what magento has to offer.  I shouldn't have overwritten the product model.

But anyway...the problem is not with the extension. it's because  of this line

```
var_dump($mainProduct->__toString());`.
```

There is no `__toString()` method in the model class. Try replacing it with something else like:

```
$mainProduct->getName();
//or
$mainProduct->getSku();
```

or anything else that can be accessed from the product instance.

and make sure you add this line at the top of your import script:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
```