# How to force only one product per order?

Tags: product, orders

I needed to force only one product per order and one amount.

The amount of the product already resolved, now need a solution for just one product per order.

A single product per application, the cart display only one product, where to buy the second notice that it is not possible to purchase more than one product per order

Comment: This is not clear. Do you want a maximum of 1 product in the shopping cart for each customer, or would you like to split an order for multiple products into multiple orders with one product?

Comment: I updated the question, I hope I have left clearer @user5972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was that I added in head.phtml the code below I made:

```
<?php
$current_page = '';
if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms'):
    $current_page = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
endif;
if(empty($current_page)):
    $current_page = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
endif;

if ($current_page == 'checkout') {
    $cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    if($quote->getItemsCount() > 1) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Message');
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $i++;
            if ($i > 1)
                $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($item->getId())->save();
                Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'd recommend against adding this code into a template. It goes against the MVC principles; as this is logic, it should be added to an appropriate class outside of the templating system. Using the event/observer pattern for this would be far better practice. If you ever change your theme, you'd lose this essential functionality; which is why it should exist outside of the templates.

Answer (score 2):

If you've already handled the amount of items per products and you want to restrict the user from adding to cart any additional products, you'll need to listen to an event to manage this. i.e. Can't add Product B, because you already have a Product A in the cart.

There's an event called `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` that may be suitable. The problem with this is that the product has already been added to the cart at this point.

Your observer would need to handle the following flow:

1. Identify the product that the user tried to add to cart
2. Remove this product from the current cart
3. Add an error message to the session

This should remove the product every single time someone tries to add it to the cart, and then from this point should inform the user that they've exceeded their maximum.

If you've no experience setting up Events and Observers, I'd recommend reading up on the matter:

http://www.solvingmagento.com/events-and-observers-a-magento-tutorial/
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-magento-observers--cms-21031

Comment: @Dexxtz let me know how it goes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in the Product configuration itself under `Inventory`

[image]

Comment: Is not the quantity of the product, but the amount of products

Comment: Ok np.  I thought it was Maximum Qty based on the original question. It appears that you want to restrict it to only 1 item in the entire cart.  If this is the case then you should see this answer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9584/how-to-allow-only-one-product-in-a-cart

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [How to allow only one product in a cart?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9584/how-to-allow-only-one-product-in-a-cart)

You could also try adding an observer for `sales_quote_add_item`

```
<sales_quote_add_item>
    <observers>
        <customoptions>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>magepal/observer</class>
            <method>checkoutCartProductAddBefore</method>
        </customoptions>
    </observers>
</sales_quote_add_item>
```

In your observer

```
.....
public function checkoutCartProductAddBefore($observer)
{
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    if($quote->getItemsCount()>=1){
        Mage::throwException('You can only buy one product at a time.');
    }
}
```