# Limit only one item in shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

Is there a way to only allow one item to be added to the shopping cart and then checked out.

I tried the event + observer addition in this link: [How to allow only one product in a cart?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9584/how-to-allow-only-one-product-in-a-cart)

But it doesn't seem to work with V1.9.2.3 As I am still able to add more than item to the cart and make it all the way to checkout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow only one product in a cart?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9584/how-to-allow-only-one-product-in-a-cart)

Comment: Post related code of what you have tried.

Comment: A created new folders under:

app/code/community/CartLimit/Cart

In there I made both an ect folder and a Model folder

The ect folder has the config.xml and the module folder contains the observer.php file

Answer (score 2):

he events `catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options` and `catalog_product_type_prepare_lite_options` are your friends

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Fooman_Example>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Fooman_Example>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <fooman_example>
                <class>Fooman_Example_Model</class>
            </fooman_example>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <fooman_example>
                <class>Fooman_Example_Helper</class>
            </fooman_example>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options>
                <observers>
                    <fooman_example_catalog_product_type_prepare>
                        <class>Fooman_Example_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>catalogProductTypePrepare</method>
                    </fooman_example_catalog_product_type_prepare>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Then in your Observer class

```
class Fooman_Example_Model_Observer
{
    public function catalogProductTypePrepare($observer)
    {
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        if($quote->getItemsCount()>=1){
            Mage::throwException('You can only buy one product at a time.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added something similar to this except it was by somebody else and where it says fooman its their signature. But I have a config file in the ect folder and then in the module folder a php file called observer with the above code

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to throw error. Rather do init checkout before add product to cart will clear the old cart and create the cart with the newly added product alone. Init checkout is a child function available in mage checkout model.