# I want to limit number of order by customer on our Sale Day

Tags: magento-1.7, orders

Actually we are going to sell Items very cheap on our Sale Day for Marketing So we want that ***one customer can place only one order on that day.***

I have already made a module so that customer will have only one product in entire cart but I am not getting how can I limit Number of orders by customer on that day.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this on a same way as you are checking cart for one product at a time.

You have to call a event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` OR `checkout_cart_product_add_before`

In this same method you will get the customer detail from session .
You just need to load all order of the current customer and filter with current date. if you get any order data then you can remove that quote and give a message there.

```
class Fooman_Example_Model_Observer
{
    public function catalogProductTypePrepare($observer)
    {
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
            $customerId = $customerData->getId();

            $fromDate = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
            $toDate = date('Y-m-d 59:59:59');
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate));
    }

        if (count($order)) {
            Mage::throwException('You already ordered today.');
        }
    }
}
```

The events xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
    <Fooman_Example>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Fooman_Example>
    </modules>
    <global>
    <models>
        <fooman_example>
            <class>Fooman_Example_Model</class>
        </fooman_example>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <fooman_example>
            <class>Fooman_Example_Helper</class>
        </fooman_example>
    </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
    <events>
        <sales_order_place_before>
        <observers>
            <library>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>library/observer</class>
            <method>AddProductSaveBefore</method>
            </library>
        </observers>
        </sales_order_place_before>
     </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: I used most voted answer on this page for one item per cart http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9584/how-to-allow-only-one-product-in-a-cart

Ashish, Can you describe in brief how to do that?

Comment: You can use my updated answer, This is not checked code so please check it properly.

Comment: Ashish, Thanks for your Help, It is working so fine after small edit but It has one issue that if customer is not logged in and then customer adds product to cart without logging in and customer logs in at checkout page and can place order successfully. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Ashish, Can we check before placing order instead of checking before adding to cart that customer has bought before or not?

Comment: Yes we can, just change the event and make a new function for this event. Check the new event in my updated answer

Comment: Can you please update according to that fooman example?

Comment: I want to merge both functionalities :- One product in Cart & One Order by One customer
Please answer this question here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135407/i-want-to-merge-two-features-one-product-per-entire-cart-limit-order-by-cus

Comment: Ashish, Can you please answer this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135407/i-want-to-merge-two-features-one-product-per-entire-cart-limit-order-by-cus

Comment: I have given the answer in this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135407/i-want-to-merge-two-features-one-product-per-entire-cart-limit-order-by-cus

I only want you to check it if its correct

Please check i Have very less time for sale start

Comment: ashish Its not working Its showing error for all orders