# I want to merge two features :- One product per entire cart & Limit order by customer

Tags: magento-1.7, orders

[How to allow only one product in a cart?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9584/how-to-allow-only-one-product-in-a-cart)

[I want to limit number of order by customer on our Sale Day](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135291/i-want-to-limit-number-of-order-by-customer-on-our-sale-day#135294)

How can i use both Features at the same time

I have given the answer, I want only a magento developer to check if its correct?

Answer (score 0):

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Fooman_Example>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Fooman_Example>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <fooman_example>
            <class>Fooman_Example_Model</class>
        </fooman_example>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <fooman_example>
            <class>Fooman_Example_Helper</class>
        </fooman_example>
    </helpers>
</global>
<frontend>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options>
            <observers>
                <fooman_example_catalog_product_type_prepare>
                    <class>Fooman_Example_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>catalogProductTypePrepare</method>
                </fooman_example_catalog_product_type_prepare>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options>
        <sales_order_place_before>
         <observers>
           <fooman_example_order_observer>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>Fooman_Example_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>AddProductSaveBefore</method>
           </fooman_example_order_observer>
         </observers>
        </sales_order_place_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Observer

```
<?php
class Fooman_Example_Model_Observer {
public function catalogProductTypePrepare($observer)
{
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
if($quote->getItemsCount()>=1){
    Mage::throwException('You can only buy one product at a time.');
}
}

public function AddProductSaveBefore($observer){
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $customerId = $customerData->getId();

    $fromDate = date('2016-09-10 00:00:00');
    $toDate = date('2016-09-10 23:59:59');
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate));
}


if($quote->getItemsCount()>=1){
    Mage::throwException('You can only Buy one product at a time. Please Change your Cart Items.');
}
if (count($order)>=1) {
    Mage::throwException('You already ordered today');
}
}
}
```