# How to create a one time purchase for each product?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have used the below code. Please suggest me if I am wrong.

```
<?php

class Fooman_Example_Model_Observer
{

    public function AddProductSaveBefore($observer)
    {
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
            $customerId = $customerData->getId();

            $time = time();
            $toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
            $lastTime = $time - 100000000; 
            $fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastTime);
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerId)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate))
            ->addFieldToFilter('sku', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getSku()))
            ->load();



        }

       if ((count($order->getItems()) - 1) >= 1) {
    Mage::throwException('You already ordered today');
}
    }
}
```

Comment: On which event you are using this observer function?

Comment: Are you referring this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9584/how-to-allow-only-one-product-in-a-cart ?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to allow max quantity. Do you want to ban that user from purchasing it again? or in that session?

[image]

Comment: I want to ban users from purchasing it again